Defining an equivalence relation through basis elements
Let $V$ be a vectorspace with some basis $\{b_1,b_2,...,\}$. V can be either finite or infinite dimensional.
Is defining some basis elements to be in relation, together with definning the relation as transitive and compatible with addition as well as scalar multiplication, enough to fully define an equivalence relation on a vector space? By transitivity and compatibility with addition and scalar multiplication I mean
$$ a\sim b, b \sim c \Rightarrow a \sim c \\ a \sim b \Rightarrow \lambda a \sim \lambda b \\ a\sim c, b \sim d \Rightarrow a+b \sim c+d$$
So the equivalence relation would be something along the lines of:
$l$ given statements on relation between basis elements, maybe there is a condition on the number and type of elements but I am not sure
$$i_s\in \{1,...,dim(V)\} \; \forall s\in \{1,..,l\}\\ I: b_{i_{1}} \sim \sum\limits_{j} f_1^{j}b_j\\II: b_{i_2} \sim \sum\limits_{j} f_2^{j}b_j\\...\\l: b_{i_l} \sim \sum\limits_{j} f_l^{j}b_j \\ \text{where the $f$s are factors}$$
Let $v_1= \sum\limits_{j} v_1^{j}b_j,v_2=\sum\limits_{j} v_2^{j}b_j \in V$ be any elements. The two elements are in relation, if you can combine the above statements to get the basis representation of $v_1$ on one side, and the basis representation of $v_2$ on the other. Maybe this process can be simplified by first fishing out all the extra statements you can form using transitivity, and then seeing if they can be linearly combined to get the searched for result.
